# Fails to update user table after inserting values from a GET form

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently working on a quiz for my class in high school.

I need to get the data from the form and then insert in and after that it should update the row inserted with the points gained doing the quiz.

Im currently usin following code, but im not getting the points update in the members database.

```
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kiggeded_marketingmix",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$q1="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '1'";
$q2="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '2'";
$q3="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '3'";
$q4="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '4'";
$q5="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '5'";
$q6="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '6'";
$q7="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '7'";
$q8="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '8'";
$q9="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '9'";
$q10="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '10'";
$q11="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '11'";
$q12="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '12'";
$q13="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '13'";
$q14="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '14'";
$q15="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '15'";
$q16="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '16'";
$q17="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '17'";
$q18="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '18'";
$q19="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '19'";
$q20="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '20'";
$q21="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '21'";
$q21="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '22'";

$point= $q1 + $q2 + $q3 + $q4 + $q5 + $q6 + $q7 + $q8 + $q9 + $q10 + $q11 + $q12 + $q13 + $q14 + $q15 + $q16 + $q17 + $q18 + $q19 + $q20 + $q21 + $q22;

$sql="INSERT INTO members 
     (uid, username, first_name, last_name, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, 
      q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, 
      q19, q20, q21, q22) VALUES
      ('$_GET[uid]', '$_GET[username]', '$_GET[first_name]', '$_GET[last_name]', '$_GET[q2]', 
       '$_GET[q3]', '$_GET[q4]', '$_GET[q5]', '$_GET[q6]', '$_GET[q7]', '$_GET[q8]', 
       '$_GET[q9]', '$_GET[q10]', '$_GET[q11]', '$_GET[q12]', '$_GET[q13]', '$_GET[q14]', 
       '$_GET[q15]', '$_GET[q16]', '$_GET[q17]', '$_GET[q18]', '$_GET[q19]', '$_GET[q20]', 
       '$_GET[q21]','$_GET[q22]')";

$sql2="UPDATE members SET point='$point' WHERE uid='$_GET[uid]'";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error()); 
$result=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: http://kiggede.dk/quiz/?tak=1");
```

Comment: what is the point field type?

Comment: **NOTE** Your code is prone to SQL injection

Comment: The point field_type is int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wall of SELECTs are useless. Reduce them to:

```
SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif BETWEEN 1 AND 22;
```

A select query **must** be executed and fetched as any other query before using any resulting data. Your code above defines strings and executes an addition of strings.

Do not calculate with php, let the Database decide if an addition should be made or not, depending on what should be updated ( or not ).

Finally: IN NO CASE DIRECTLY CONCATINATE $_GET VALUES TO A QUERY STRING. You have to escape them first to grand the required security to your database ( have a look at mysql_real_escape_string() ).

As a hint for the future: I recommend to use prepared statements in any case. I also recommend to use MySQLi ( or better PDO ) for database interactions. The PHP MySQL-Extension is deprecated with PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your complete code you forgot to actually select the points from database.

```
$q1="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '1'";
$result1=mysql_query($q1,$conn)
$q2="SELECT point FROM questions WHERE dif = '2'";
$result2=mysql_query($q2,$conn)
[...]
```

I would also suggest to count all at once as in

```
$q="SELECT count(point) FROM questions WHERE dif between 1 and 22";
$result=mysql_query($q,$conn)
```

Answer (score -1):

`uid` should be quoted when accessing `$_GET`

```
$sql2="UPDATE members SET point='$point' WHERE uid = '" . $_GET['uid'] . "'";
```

However, this code is extremely prone to SQL injection. You should sanitize user input.